# PHP Form Post/Redirect/Get Header Location Error

Tags: php, html, forms, post-redirect-get

I have a simple form that I've made to help me learn php. I'm using my local host server to host the php file (form.php). However, when I refresh the page it resubmits the form, I know I can use the post/redirect/get method to negate this problem. Except implementing the header('Location: form.php'); hasn't been working, if you could take a look at the code- and tell me what I'm doing wrong, that would be much appreciated.

Code example i.e without header('Location: form.php');

```
<?php 
if (empty($_POST) === false) {
    echo '<pre>', print_r($_POST, true), '</pre>';
    }
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Form</title>
  </head>
<body>

<form action="form.php" method="post">
  <p>
    <label for="name">Name:</label><br>
    <input type="text" name="name" id="name"><br>
  </p>
  <p>
    <label for="email">Email:</label><br>
    <input type="text" name="email" id="email"><br>
  </p>
  <p>
    <label for="message">Message:</label><br>
    <textarea name="message" id="message"></textarea>
  </p>
  <p>
    <input type="submit" value="submit">
  </p>
</form>
```

This is the result...

> Screen Shot without header location

[image]

then I add:

```
header('Location: form.php');
```

And I get this...

[image]

Comment: Where is the redirect code and where exactly are you placing it?  The screenshots do not help in figuring out the problem.

Comment: Seems like you're redirecting the page to itself.

Comment: its need to full path of you form.php file

Comment: Show us where you added the `header()`-call. We need to see the code that's not working to be able to help you.

Answer (score 0):

To prevent a form from resubmitting on page refresh, two methods are used:

**Method 1: Use AJAX + Redirect**

Submit your form using AJAX and then redirect to another page using JQuery.

**Method 2: Reload the page**

Refresh the page using Javascript.

Your code should be like this:

```
    <?php 
        if (!empty($_POST)) {
            echo '<pre>', print_r($_POST, true), '</pre>';
            echo '<script type="text/javascript"> location.reload();</script>';
        }
    ?>

    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
       <head>
         <meta charset="utf-8">
         <title>Form</title>
       </head>
       <body>

        <form action="form.php" method="post">
          <p>
            <label for="name">Name:</label><br>
            <input type="text" name="name" id="name"><br>
          </p>
          <p>
            <label for="email">Email:</label><br>
            <input type="text" name="email" id="email"><br>
          </p>
          <p>
            <label for="message">Message:</label><br>
            <textarea name="message" id="message"></textarea>
          </p>
          <p>
            <input type="submit" value="submit">
          </p>
        </form>
       </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Your code example will fail, since your outputting content before the `header()`-call. All headers must be called _before_ any other output, or you will get "Headers already sent". You should also have an `exit;` after the header call to stop the parser from continuing the script.

Comment: You are right. I just edited my answer. Thank you :)

Comment: Emptying the POST array is unnecessary and bad practice.  What if you want to see what  was posted later in the script?  And how would this prevent the poster's issue?

Comment: Actually, the new answer isn't correct either. When you refresh a post request, the same request will be sent again (it's the browser that remembers the request). The `$_POST`-array is simply an array that get's populated with a _copy_ the post data. It's not the _actual_ post request.

Comment: @MattS: Yes, it's a bad practice. If you want to see values later in the page you can store them in other variables or clone the whole array.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson: I used this method and it worked for me.

Comment: I just tried and no cigar. It still asks to resubmit the form when you hit "refresh" on the page. The `$_POST`-array is still just a copy of the posted data. Changing that won't change the browsers history

Comment: @MagnusEriksson: I just edited the answer by reloading the page using javascript.